# find out a point is in which polygons

Tags: polygon, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper, point-in-polygon

I have a region table in oracle 12c, the table include 9 region that each of them defined by a polygon.
Polygon defined by 4 points in 2D.
I give a point from client and I must find out that this point is in which polygon. can anyone help me with this problem?
by the way I use Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

Ray casting algorithm is a popular solution to your problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon. You can find pseudo-code easily and can start from that.

If you want to have solution in a specific language, then sorry I can't be of help.